# All Angular Unit Tests erroring with "Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive ...."

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

All of the boilerplate tests than Angular creates are failing to build. Taking an example:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { CheckboxComponent } from './checkbox.component';

fdescribe('CheckboxComponent', () => {
  let component: CheckboxComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CheckboxComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CheckboxComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CheckboxComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Whenever I run `ng test` it fails with `Illegal state: Could not load the summary for directive CheckboxComponent`. We have about a dozen components and they all fail in this way.

The application builds and runs both in development and prod mode without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

This problem to have been caused by a completely unrelated directive unit test failing.

The frustrating this is, only the CheckboxComponent test suite was being run (with the `fdescribe` tag, and there were no errors that gave the correct name of the other test suite (which should have been excluded as it did not have the `fdescribe` tag).

The solution was to rename all 102 test spec files from `.spec.ts` to `.spec.bak` and add them back in one by one to find out which test was failing.